# How do I format a scientific number into decimal format in Python?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble trying to convert the results of my "def pricing(question)" function into decimal values instead of scientific.

I tried converting the result to a string but that didn't work and I can't see anyway of formatting the pricex variables where they are.

Any help is much appreciated

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UmXK.png)

[image]
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzSHS.png)

[image]

Comment: You should post your code in the question. You can format it by highlighting it and pressing CTRL+k

Comment: This question has already been answered on SO: [Convert Scientific Notation to Decimal - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962512/convert-scientific-notation-to-decimal-python)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a formatting string.

```
>>> import math
>>> print(math.pi)
3.141592653589793
>>> print("{:.2f}".format(math.pi))
3.14
```