# Convert a scientific notation to decimal number, and still keeping the data format as float64

Tags: python, numpy, casting, precision

I have a simple question.

I am using the `numpy.std` formula to calculate the standard deviation. However, the result comes as a number in scientific notation.

Therefore I am asking, How to convert a scientific notation to decimal number, and still keep the data format as float64 ?

Or is there any workaround to get the initial result as a decimal number?

**Solutions such as this:**

```
stdev = format(stdev, '.10f')
```

converts the data into a string object, which I don't want.

ere is my code:

```
stdev = numpy.std(dataset)
print(stdev)
```

Result: 4.999999999999449e-05

```
print(stdev.dtype)
```

Result: float64

**Expected result**

I willing to have a result as a decimal number in a float64 format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert scientific notation to decimal - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962512/convert-scientific-notation-to-decimal-python)

Comment: Scientific notation is a display method, not the actual number.   `0.00005` is displayed as "5e-05".   You can use a print format to control the display, for example: `"%f"%0.00005`.  Look at the docs for `np.set_printoptions` to see how you can control the display of numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is just a matter of representation since the data type, as you showed, is still float64.

If this is right, you can just print as a formatted string:

```
>>> x = 123456789e-15
>>> print(x)
1.23456789e-07

>>> print("{:.15f}".format(x))
0.000000123456789
```

The `.15f` specifies that you want a float format with 15 decimals.

From python 3.6 you can use the f-string format:

```
print(f"{x:.15f}")
0.000000123456789
```

Have a look at the [string format documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Comment: `print("{:.15f}".format(x))`  this command may create an immediate output as a decimal number without string specifications. However when I assign this output to variable such as y, like :  `y="{:.15f}".format(x)`  the `y` object is not float anymore. It becomes a string.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your question then. When you print a float it is converted to a string by python, so you are always seeing a string printed out. Depending on the number of decimal digits it may be printed in scientific notation (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24187684/python-change-repr-floating-digits). Nevertheless, the way a float is stored in memory does not depend on how you see it printed out by the print funcition.

Answer (score 0):

You confuse representation and internal storage. By default, Python will show the value in the scientific form. You can force another form of representation - but you cannot affect the value itself.

Vanilla Python does not have a notion of *float64* (it is not that great for exact calculations) - but **numpy** does

[image]